# Adding Company Web App to Office 365

Tags: asp.net, office365

so I don't know a whole lot about Office 365 and have been learning other frameworks that do not include ASP.NET.

The company I work for is using is Office 365 and CRM. I read you can interface CRM with a web app. What I am wondering is if a company had a web application they used on their intranet, is it possible to migrate it to Office 365? Possibly as a Site? Is it possible to develop a web app that shows up under Office 365 and is therefore accessible to employees at that Office 365 account? You would need access to the MS SQL and IIS web server running, can you get that kind of access through Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, you can have your application hosted on Azure or anywhere with all you backend and host it as an App in o365.

What i suggest you to do, Get Office Development tools for VS 2015, just create a project from under **Office/SharePoint** section and select SharePoint Add-In project template and check out the created project. you will see that an asp.net web project has been created and another project as a shell for deploying this app as SP app. you do have the option to host this app anywhere :)

Check out this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can build a web application and have it appear in the Office 365 app launcher.  However, there are some specific architectural requirements such as integration with Azure AD and single sign-on.

Have a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/connect-your-app-to-o365-app-launcher?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396